# Check the difference between two Environments?

Tags: metadata

We have moved our data from Dev environment to production. And later we made few changes in Dev. How can we know the differences that are made in dev which do not exist in production?

Comment: One option if you dont use  version control is View Setup Audit Trails

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Gearset](https://gearset.com/), a tool we use in our org all the time (I am not a Gearset employee nor contractor). There's a free trial

Gearset can compare any two orgs or orgs to source control. You can compare based on metadata API type (i.e. custom object, apex class, report, etc.). The comparisons come back in a nice difference viewer.

Gearset is of course much more than just org compare as it is a devops tool for Salesforce - CI, deployment, unit test, data deploy, etc.

Comment: +1 for Gearset!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [this](https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/):

Don't know if it helps but it will allow you to compare 2 orgs.
It will take sometime before getting the output. :)